# Python dictionaries: any way to check for 'similar' key?

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets say I had a dictionary with some key: value pairs. Instead of redefining the dictionary, is there any way to check if something is similar to some key in the dictionary?

For Example

```
items = [ 'green apple', 'yellow pepper', 'green pepper', 'red pepper' ] 
fruitsandveggies = { 'apple': 2, 'banana': 5, 'pepper': 6}
for item in items:        
    if item is similar to some key in fruitsandveggies ('green apple' is similar to 'apple',
    set qty = value of that key 
    then print that qty
```

To clear up some questions, what I mean by similar is simply containing the 'key' in the string. So 'crab apple', 'green apple', 'washington apple' all contain 'apple' in them, which is one of the keys.

Comment: How is `green apple` similar to apple? If coz of name, then what about `pine apple`?

Comment: Define similar.  If `pepper` is similar to `green pepper` is `green pepper` also similar to `pepper`?  Is `green pepper` similar to `green apple`?  Is `orange` similar to `orange pepper`?

Comment: Yes, but you are going to have to be much more specific about what counts as "similar".  Does "crab apple" count as similar?  Does "Manzana" (Spanish for apple) count?  Does "applle" or "aple" count as similar"  How about "Apple" or "APPLE"?

Comment: Also, note that checking for *'similarity'* is going to seriously impact the performance of the dictionary.

Comment: Piggybacking on @jonrsharpe's comment.  Once you've defined similar and implemented a function for it the only way to test for similarity is to *iterate over every key* which pretty much defeats the purpose of having a dictionary.

Comment: I have edited the question to make things more clear

Comment: @ohbrobig OK, so where is your code? Have you made an attempt to implement it? What happened?

Comment: why not just iterate over the keys and do `key in item`? Won't be the most efficient way but definitely works

Comment: [PEP-455](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0455/) may be somewhat applicable here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) that will return a measure of the sequences similarity as a float in the range `[0, 1]`.

And `max` function :

```
>>> fruitsandveggies = { 'apple': 2, 'banana': 5, 'pepper': 6}
>>> max(fruitsandveggies.items(),key=lambda (i,j):difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, i,'green apple').ratio())
('apple', 2)
```

If you just want to get the value use a simple indexing (`[1]`)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think this is what you want to do:

```
import re

items = [ 'green apple', 'yellow pepper', 'green pepper', 'red pepper' ] 
fruitsandveggies = { 'apple': 2, 'banana': 5, 'pepper': 6}
for key in fruitsandveggies.keys():
    fruitsandveggies[key] = 0
    for item in items:
        if re.search(key, item): # if it finds the key string in the item
            fruitsandveggies[key] += 1
    #print str(fruitsandveggies[key]) + ' ' + key #python 2
    print(str(fruitsandveggies[key]) + ' ' + key) #python 3
```

it will print

3 pepper
1 apple
0 banana

in this example

Comment: You can do `print(fruitsandveggies[key], key)` and avoid all type casting

Comment: If the `re.search(...)` call stays as simple as this, you could replace it with `in`. Otherwise, you should implement things as `re.IGNORECASE`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in items:
    if any(key in i for key in fruitsandveggies.keys()):
        print key # or print fruitsandveggies[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question right, but the following is a way to check items for strings similar to the keys of the dictionary:

```
for key in fruitsandveggies:
    if any(key in item for item in items):
        qty = fruitsandveggies[key]
        print(qty)
```